# Javascript - Where exactly to place try - catch?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Try catch is used to catch errors and report to user. all said and fine. But where exactly one has to put the try-catch. Or What exactly has to go inside try catch on a usual basis.

Most importantly, is it absolutely a good coding practice to have a try catch block?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is good practce to use a try catch if it will handle errors and prevent the program from crashing.

Taken from W3 Schools:

> 1. The try statement lets you test a block of code for errors.
> 2. The catch statement lets you handle the error.
> 3. The throw statement lets you create custom errors.
> 4. The finally statement lets you execute
>      code, after try and catch, regardless of the result.

An example:

```
fuction  foo()
{
   try
   {
      // Block of code to try
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      //  Block of code to handle errors
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e.message;
   }
   finally 
   {
     // Block of code to be executed regardless of the try / catch result
   }
}
```

Here is soem more documentation at W3 Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it absolutely good practice to use try-catch blocks. Here's a rather simplistic (but contrived) demonstration.

```
function safeParseJSON(json) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(json);
  } catch(exception) {
    // could not parse this JSON
    console.error(exception);
  } finally {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Parsing JSON is the most common scenario I have encountered for using the try-catch construct, hence the example.

**However**, the usual try-catch mechanism doesn't work when the function is asynchronous. It's essential to understand this if you are ever using a [server side Javascript platform](http://nodejs.org/).

The standard pattern for async event handling is as follows.

```
db.connect(options, function connected(err, client) {
  if(err) throw err;

  client.query(...);
});
```

Because that callback function is run somewhere else (presumably when the database connects) we can't wrap it with a try-catch block. Instead, most async method calls will pass the error as the first argument to the callback.

This way we can handle the error as and when it happens. If there is no error, `null` will be passed as the first argument, so that it can be ignored.

A number of implementations of [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) try to recreate this mechanism, but in an asynchronous way.

Here's an example with [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

```
db.connect(options)
.then(function(client) {
  client.query(...);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  throw error;
})
.fin(function() {
  // finally
  db.close();
});
```

You can also use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) on the client side, if you are working with asynchronous functions.